# Easiest way to print Datagrid

Tags: c#, datagrid

Trying to print a datagrid in silverlight triggered by a button
Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Use classes of [System.Windows.Printing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee652643%28v=VS.96%29.aspx) Namespace.

Articles :

1. [Making printing easier in Silverlight](http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/04/16/making-printing-easier-in-silverlight-4/)
2. [Advanced printing in Silverlight](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Advanced-printing-in-Silverlight-4.aspx)

Comment: I think that is for Windows Forms.

Comment: +1, cool article, but you need to change your namespace and link.  They use the `PrintDocument` class from the [System.Windows.Printing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee652643(v=VS.96).aspx) namespace.

Answer (score 0):

referring to this article [Printing in silverlight](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1366-print-document-silverlight-40.aspx)

Use `System.Windows.Printing.PrintDocument`
There are three events to handles printing. They are

- EndPrint
- StartPrint
- PrintPage

use Print() to do the print operation
set the DocumentName property for the name.

- Create instance of `PrintDocument` class
- Specify the content to print.
- Write code to handle the `PagePrint` event

  private void mybutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    PrintDocument prt = new PrintDocument();
    prt.PrintPage +=(s,args) =>
    {
    args.PageVisual = txtBlcok;
    };
    prt.Print();
  }